# Properties of matrix of linear transformation w.r.t an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, inner-products

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional Inner Product Space and $T : V \to V$ be linear operator.
 I just wondered what can be some special properties of matrix of $T$ w.r.t an orthonormal basis.
 I cannot see it clearly if any.
 Is it orthogonal. If so how can we prove it??
Kindly help! Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A useful property is that the matrix of the adjoint $T^*$ w.r.t an orthonormal basis $E$  is given by the conjugate transpose of the matrix of $T$, i.e. $$(T^*)_{(E)} = (T_{(E)})^*$$

From there you can infer:

- $T$ is normal if and only if $T_{(E)}$ is a normal matrix
- $T$ is self-adjoint if and only if $T_{(E)}$ is a hermitian matrix
- $T$ is unitary if and only if $T_{(E)}$ is a unitary matrix